# Jquery validate free emails using validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I used jquery validator for validation.I have 50 free emails like(gmail.com, yahoo.com) so I need validate it.I chose an array then stored all the emails within an array.Below see my code there you could see I used the regular expression.I passed a variable in regular expression but it doesn't work for me.It threw the error like this **SyntaxError: invalid range in character class**

My code

```
$.validator.addMethod('nofreeemail', function (value) {
   var emails = ["gmail.com","yahoo.com","hotmail.com"]
   $.each(emails,function(i, val){
     console.log("email", val)
     var regex = new RegExp("/^([\w-.]+@(?!"+val+")([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/");
     console.log("regex", regex)
     return regex.test(value);
   });
}, 'Free email addresses are not allowed.');
```

Comment: Since you don't care about the first part of the email address, why don't you just split it at the `@` and check the second part against your list of free hosters?

Comment: Remove the regex delimiters from the constructor notation. You are passing a string literal pattern, not the regex literal. And double backslashes and escape the `val`: `var regex = new RegExp("^([\\w-.]+@(?!"+val.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')+")([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]{2,4})?$");`. I also believe the dot in `([\w-]+.)+` must be escaped, it is supposed to match a literal dot, right?

Comment: Why not just `var regex = new RegExp("/^([\w-.]+@" + val + "$/");`

Comment: @Karthick, did it work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I tried your code on my local server and browser console(chrome, firefox) but I got error like this **SyntaxError: illegal character**

Comment: @VadimB, I tried your code too.what I posted above the same error is coming.

Comment: @Karthick: You copied/pasted the code from the body of the answer, but SO added garbage char right after `/g` before `,`. I have edited the post in such a way that SO no longer inserts those chars. Pease retry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post an answer since it is not evident here what is going on, but the underlying reasons are quite common.

You are using a constructor notation to define the regex. It is a correct approach when you need to build a pattern dynamically using a variable. However, a literal backslash must be written as `"\\"`. All single backslashes are removed. Thus, you get an error since `[\w-.]`  turns into `[w-.]` and it is an invalid character class. Also, the regex delimiters (those `/..../` around the pattern) should never be used in the constructor notation unless you really need to match a string enclosed with `/`.

Besides, your `emails` contain non-word chars, and you need to escape them.

Use

```
var regex = new RegExp("^([\\w-.]+@(?!"+val.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g,'\\$&')+")([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]{2,4})?$");
```

I also believe the dot in `([\w-]+.)+` must be escaped, it is supposed to match a literal dot,